# Is it secure to make adobe flash website?

Tags: wordpress, security, flash, web

I am making a website using adobe flash and action script. but I heard a lot about flash vulnerabilities.

Is it secure to make a website using adobe flash, comparably to ordinary tools like wordpress and joomla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory Flash is secure, but I would recommend not using it.
The reasons Flash has many vulnerabilities is not because of the websites using it, but the clients not updating their Flash clients. Your site depends on the client for security which is almost always a bad idea.

There also is a second reason not to use Flash and that is compatibility. Flash won't work on iPhones, Android Phones, Windows Phones and it won't take long before all browsers will block it ([Firefox already does that!](http://gizmodo.com/firefox-now-blocks-flash-by-default-1717664482)).

And the third argument is that it just is not necessary to use Flash anymore. You can use HTML, CSS3 and maybe a bit of JavaScript to be able to do anything Flash once was unique in.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, +1. I just did not understand how the website will depends for the client for security. Did you mean that if the client did not update their Flash player, pirates could use this flash player to attack my website?

Comment: @ProEns08 No it will not affect your site in most cases (except if you build a CMS in Flash or something). But it could compensate the information send and received by the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case, I am making a CMS website in flash. Did that mean that I could have attacks on my website?

Comment: @ProEns08 Let me sketch a scenario here: You've created an CMS (Not anything frontend related, really the CMS) in Flash and you've given someone access to your content. This person does not have the newest version of Flash and he also has an so called "man in the middle" virus. He/she edits some content, but instead of the content, the hacker sends some malicious code to the site, giving all your clients a virus. Keep in mind though that this is only the case if the CMS ITSELF has been coded in Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Flash make your page to load very slow.
If site is created only in flash? not only a part of it(like header logo and other) the user will wait while all flash will load and this take times and very expensive traffic if is used mobile device to connect PC to internet (usb 4G modem, or mobile built in modem ).